# Is there some sort of max limit when forking from repos on github?

Tags: github, git-fork

Currently when I try to fork from certain repositories I am met with this:

[image: Fork error]

I am still able to fork from some other repos though

Comment: There's no limit, but a repository can set a flag to prevent itself from being forked.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking if you were able to solve this problem, in my case my organisation is a free one with enterprise capabilities and had to change the visibility to internal solved my problem.